# ORACLE : conditional GROUP BY depending upon SELECT clause

Tags: oracle, group-by

I am stuck at situation where I need to use conditional `GROUP BY` clause depending upon `SELECT` clause, here is my code its not the actual one, I just tried to create a dummy example.

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
 id NUMBER,
 value1 NUMBER,
 value2 NUMBER,
 value3 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1,100,100,100);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (2,100,100,100);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (3,100,100,100);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (4,100,100,100);

SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN 2 > 1 THEN MIN(id)
    WHEN 1 > 2 THEN MAX(id)
    ELSE id
  END, 
  value1, 
  value2, 
  value3 
FROM temp 
GROUP BY 
  CASE WHEN 2 > 1  THEN value1 END,
  CASE WHEN 2 > 1  THEN value2 END,
  CASE WHEN 2 > 1  THEN value3 END;
```

Here it gives following error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 18 Column: 9
```

I just need to know is this the right way or how can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `2 > 1`

Comment: its just a random Condition, actually those are pl sql block variables

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: depending upon condition in select it should select`MIN`, `MAX` etc

Comment: Edit your question for the sample data what should come out?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> GROUP BY 
>   CASE WHEN 2 > 1  THEN value1 END,
>   CASE WHEN 2 > 1  THEN value2 END,
>   CASE WHEN 2 > 1  THEN value3 END;
> ```

Your **CASE expression** is incorrect in the **GROUP BY** clause. All those multiple case statements makes no sense and it is **syntactically** incorrect. You need something like this -

```
group by (
 case
    when condition1 then result1
    when condition2 then result2
    else result3
 end)
```

OR,

Use an **in-line view**.

```
SELECT ...
  FROM (SELECT (case
                   when condition1 then result1
                   when condition2 then result2
                   else result3
                end) alias_view
          FROM your_table)
GROUP BY alias_view;
```